# Creating Multi-Tabbed Grid with Preserved Contents and Overview Grid

Tags: programming, grid-layouts, gui-construction

I am in the process of creating an application/panel that will aide me in scheduling hours for my staff of ten or more. I am hoping to create a multi-tabbed grid within which I may collect data about my staff and ultimately create a final schedule based on their choices. I have started the code, but I find myself stuck in a couple places:
creating a grid that pulls that data from the other grids to give an overview of the schedule (in order to find overlapping hours, holes in the schedule, etc.),
saving the data in the input fields once entered, and counting the number of check boxes that are ticked on each tab. My code can be found below, any guidance, help, or thoughts would be very helpful at this point. Thank you.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f = Enabled -> False;
m = ImageMargins -> 20;
week =
  Grid[{
    {"", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
     "Saturday", "Sunday"},
    {"8:00 AM", Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], 
     Checkbox[m], Checkbox[f], Checkbox[f]},
    {"9:00 AM", Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], 
     Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m]},
    {"10:00 AM", Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], 
     Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m]},
    {"11:00 AM", Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], 
     Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m]},
    {"12:00 PM", Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], 
     Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m]},
    {"1:00 PM", Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], 
     Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m]},
    {"2:00 PM", Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], 
     Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m]},
    {"3:00 PM", Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], 
     Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m]},
    {"4:00 PM", Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], 
     Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m]},
    {"5:00 PM", Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], 
     Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m]},
    {"6:00 PM", Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], 
     Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m]},
    {"7:00 PM", Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], 
     Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m]},
    {"8:00 PM", Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], 
     Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m]},
    {"9:00 PM", Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], 
     Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m]},
    {"10:00 PM", Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], 
     Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m]},
    {"11:00 PM", Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], 
     Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m]},
    {"12:00 AM", Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], 
     Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m]},
    {"1:00 AM", Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], 
     Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m]},
    {"2:00 AM", Checkbox[f], Checkbox[f], Checkbox[f], Checkbox[m], 
     Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[f]},
    {"3:00 AM", Checkbox[f], Checkbox[f], Checkbox[f], Checkbox[m], 
     Checkbox[m], Checkbox[m], Checkbox[f]}
    }, Frame -> All];
Clear[ln, fn, ws, ln2, fn2, ws2, ln3, fn3, ws3]
input =
  Panel[
   Grid[{
     {""},
     {Style["Front Desk Assignment Preferences", 14, Bold], 
      SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
     {""},
     {"Last Name:", InputField[Dynamic[ln], String], SpanFromLeft, 
      SpanFromLeft},
     {"First Name:", InputField[Dynamic[fn], String], SpanFromLeft, 
      SpanFromLeft},
     {"-----------------------------------------------", SpanFromLeft,
       SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
     {"Workstudy:", RadioButtonBar[2, {1 -> "Yes", 2 -> "No"}], 
      SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
     {"Workstudy Amount:  $", 
      InputField[Dynamic[n], Number, FieldSize -> 10], SpanFromLeft, 
      SpanFromLeft},
     {"-----------------------------------------------", SpanFromLeft,
       SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
     {"Weekend Preference:", 
      RadioButtonBar[3, {1 -> "A", 2 -> "B", 3 -> "Either"}], 
      SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
     {""},
     {"-----------------------------------------------", SpanFromLeft,
       SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
     {Style[
       "Please select the hours you are interested in working from \
the table below:", Bold], SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
     {week, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
     {""}
     }, Alignment -> Left]];
input2 =
  Panel[
   Grid[{
     {""},
     {Style["Front Desk Assignment Preferences", 14, Bold], 
      SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
     {""},
     {"Last Name:", InputField[Dynamic[ln2], String], SpanFromLeft, 
      SpanFromLeft},
     {"First Name:", InputField[Dynamic[fn2], String], SpanFromLeft, 
      SpanFromLeft},
     {"-----------------------------------------------", SpanFromLeft,
       SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
     {"Workstudy:", RadioButtonBar[2, {1 -> "Yes", 2 -> "No"}], 
      SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
     {"Workstudy Amount:  $", 
      InputField[Dynamic[n2], Number, FieldSize -> 10], SpanFromLeft, 
      SpanFromLeft},
     {"-----------------------------------------------", SpanFromLeft,
       SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
     {"Weekend Preference:", 
      RadioButtonBar[3, {1 -> "A", 2 -> "B", 3 -> "Either"}], 
      SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
     {""},
     {"-----------------------------------------------", SpanFromLeft,
       SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
     {Style[
       "Please select the hours you are interested in working from \
the table below:", Bold], SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
     {week, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
     {""}
     }, Alignment -> Left]];
input3 =
  Panel[
   Grid[{
     {""},
     {Style["Front Desk Assignment Preferences", 14, Bold], 
      SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
     {""},
     {"Last Name:", InputField[Dynamic[ln3], String], SpanFromLeft, 
      SpanFromLeft},
     {"First Name:", InputField[Dynamic[fn3], String], SpanFromLeft, 
      SpanFromLeft},
     {"-----------------------------------------------", SpanFromLeft,
       SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
     {"Workstudy:", RadioButtonBar[2, {1 -> "Yes", 2 -> "No"}], 
      SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
     {"Workstudy Amount:  $", 
      InputField[Dynamic[n3], Number, FieldSize -> 10], SpanFromLeft, 
      SpanFromLeft},
     {"-----------------------------------------------", SpanFromLeft,
       SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
     {"Weekend Preference:", 
      RadioButtonBar[3, {1 -> "A", 2 -> "B", 3 -> "Either"}], 
      SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
     {""},
     {"-----------------------------------------------", SpanFromLeft,
       SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
     {Style[
       "Please select the hours you are interested in working from \
the table below:", Bold], SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
     {week, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
     {""}
     }, Alignment -> Left]];
final = TabView[{"Worker 1" -> input, "Worker 2" -> input2, 
   "Worker 3" -> input3}]
```

Comment: Just my opinion, but I think a spreadsheet is better for this sort of thing than _Mathematica_.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
 2)[`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking 
the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system 
is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to 
accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, 
[`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)

Comment: @m_goldberg: Excel was my first thought, but I ran into serious problems when it came to finding a way to consolidate all the staff on the "All" sheet in a manner that gave me more information than just the sum of those interested in that particular time slot. Do you have any thoughts on how I could better accomplish what I'm attempting in Excel? If so, I'd be very interested. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 DynamicModule[{n = 3,
  prefTable = ConstantArray[0, {3, 20, 7}],
  lastName = ConstantArray["", {3}],
  firstName = ConstantArray["", {3}],
  ws = ConstantArray[0, {3}],
  wsAmount = ConstantArray[Null, {3}],
  wkndPref = ConstantArray[Null, {3}],
  tabLabel = Array["Worker " <> ToString[#] &, {3}],
  hours = DateString[DatePlus[{2012, 1, 1, 7, 0, 0}, {#, "Hour"}],
     {"Hour12", ":", "Minute", " ", "AMPM"}] & /@ Range[20],
  colLabels = {"", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
    "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"},
  sFL = SpanFromLeft, combined, prefs, infoTable },
prefs[index_] := Grid[Prepend[Transpose[Prepend[
  Transpose@Outer[Checkbox[Dynamic[prefTable[[index, #1, #2]]], {0, 1}] &,
    Range[20], Range[7]], hours]], colLabels], Frame -> All];
combined = Panel@Grid[Prepend[Transpose[Prepend[Transpose@Outer[Row[Join[{             
        Dynamic[Style[Total[prefTable[[All, #1, #2]]], "Subsection"]], " "},
        Table[With[{i = i}, Checkbox[Dynamic[prefTable[[i, #1, #2]]], {0, 1}]],
         {i, Length[prefTable]}]]] &,
     Range[20], Range[7]], hours]], colLabels], Frame -> All];
infoTable[index_] := Panel[Grid[{{""},
   {Style["Front Desk Assignment Preferences", 14, Bold],  sFL, sFL, sFL}, {""},
   {"Last Name:", InputField[Dynamic[lastName[[index]],
    ((lastName[[index]] = #; tabLabel[[index]] = lastName[[index]]) &)], String], 
     sFL, sFL}, 
   {"First Name:", InputField[Dynamic[firstName[[index]]], String], sFL,  sFL}, 
      {"-----------------------------------------------", sFL, sFL, sFL},
   {"Workstudy:", RadioButtonBar[Dynamic[ws[[index]]], {1->"Yes", 2->"No"}], sFL, sFL},
   {"Workstudy Amount: $", InputField[Dynamic[wsAmount[[index]]],
     Number, FieldSize -> 10, Enabled -> Dynamic[ws[[index]] == 1]], sFL, sFL},
   {"-----------------------------------------------", sFL, sFL, sFL}, 
   {"Weekend Preference:", RadioButtonBar[Dynamic[wkndPref[[index]]],
    {1 -> "A", 2 -> "B", 3 -> "Either"}], sFL, sFL}, {""},
   {"-----------------------------------------------", sFL, sFL, sFL}, 
   {Style["Please select the hours you are interested in working from the table below:",
      Bold],
   sFL, sFL, sFL}, {prefs[index], sFL, sFL, sFL}, {""}}, Alignment -> Left]];

 Deploy@TabView[Join @@ {Dynamic[tabLabel[[#]]] -> infoTable[#] & /@ Range[n],
     {"All" -> combined}}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance and help in my endeavor! I was wondering how to cleanly increase the number of staff (as I have ten to fifteen at any given time of the year)? In this sense, I'm not worried about the width of the "All" tab, as this will greatly increase by adding more checkboxes.

Answer (score 3):

This is only a partial answer -- maybe only a fraction of a partial answer.

1. You define only one grid,`week`, which appears on all three panels. This means each of your workers is entering his/her choices into the same checkboxes, effectively undoing each other's choices. You really need a function that will return a new copy of your grid each time it is called.
2. Your checkboxes need to have a value holder as their first arguments. Each value holder needs to be unique. The function that generates your grid might take an array of value holders for the worker choices as an argument and insert the array elements into the checkboxes. You will need to associate a array of such value holders with each of the workers.
3. Each worker needs to have a representation in your code. You will collect and store the data from the input panels in these representations.

Comment: To save the data, use `DynamicModule`. For details, see [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html#877365235).

Comment: @Z-Y.L I wouldn't trust that. I'd go for an explicit save.

Comment: @m_goldberg: Thanks for the input, the items you bring up certainly crossed my mind, but I'm not incredibly experienced with Mathematica and was not able to find a way to do the prescribed items listed above. I am slowly learning though. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a smaller example

```
With[{dims = {5, 5}},
 DynamicModule[{w1, w2},
  w1 = w2 = ConstantArray[False, dims];
  Panel@Column[{
     TabView[{"Worker 1", "Worker 2", "Both"} -> Append[
         Function[i, 
           Grid@Array[Checkbox[Dynamic[i[[#1, #2]]]] &, dims], 
           HoldAll] /@ Unevaluated@{w1, w2},
         Dynamic@
          Grid@Map[Checkbox[#, Enabled -> False] &, 
            Thread /@ Thread[w1 || w2], {2}]] // Thread],
     Row[{"Total: ", Dynamic@Total@Boole@Flatten@{w1, w2}, 
       Spacer[50], 
       Button["Save", 
        Save[SystemDialogInput["FileSave", "workers.txt"], {w1, w2}], 
        Method -> "Queued"]}]}]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is definitely something I will implement in the final version of the application. I like how clean and simple the functionality behaves. And the "Total" counter was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.