# Creating Scheduler

Tags: dynamic

I am trying to build a scheduler program like pizza delivery. Each driver will choose their time and general working schedule will be updated similarly.

Problem is number of workers change.

How can I make this for dynamically changing variable?

Here is an example:

[image: Scheduler]

I can do it if I define individual parameters for every cell in the tables. 
Number of workers/drivers could change, so it should be defined dynamically.

This is an example code.

```
ClearAll[i];
totTime = 12;
porTime = 2; (*Time portion*)
startTime = 8;

workingTable = 
  Table[ToString[hour] <> ToString[day], {hour, 
totTime/porTime}, {day, 6}];
PrependTo[
  workingTable, {"Time", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
"Friday"}];

For[i = 1, i <= (totTime/porTime), i++,
  workingTable[[i + 1, 1]] = 
   ToString[startTime] <> ":00 - " <> ToString[startTime + porTime] <>
 ":00";
  startTime = startTime + porTime ;
  ];

worker1 = workingTable;
worker2 = workingTable;

worker1[[2, 2]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X21]]; 
worker1[[2, 3]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X22]]; 
worker1[[2, 4]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X23]]; 
worker1[[2, 5]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X24]]; 
worker1[[2, 6]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X25]];
worker1[[3, 2]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X31]]; 
worker1[[3, 3]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X32]]; 
worker1[[3, 4]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X33]]; 
worker1[[3, 5]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X34]]; 
worker1[[3, 6]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X35]];
worker1[[4, 2]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X41]]; 
worker1[[4, 3]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X42]]; 
worker1[[4, 4]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X43]]; 
worker1[[4, 5]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X44]]; 
worker1[[4, 6]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X45]];
worker1[[5, 2]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X51]]; 
worker1[[5, 3]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X52]]; 
worker1[[5, 4]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X53]]; 
worker1[[5, 5]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X54]]; 
worker1[[5, 6]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X55]];
worker1[[6, 2]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X61]]; 
worker1[[6, 3]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X62]]; 
worker1[[6, 4]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X63]]; 
worker1[[6, 5]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X64]]; 
worker1[[6, 6]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X65]];
worker1[[7, 2]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X71]]; 
worker1[[7, 3]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X72]]; 
worker1[[7, 4]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X73]]; 
worker1[[7, 5]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X74]]; 
worker1[[7, 6]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[X75]];

worker2[[2, 2]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y21]]; 
worker2[[2, 3]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y22]]; 
worker2[[2, 4]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y23]]; 
worker2[[2, 5]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y24]]; 
worker2[[2, 6]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y25]];
worker2[[3, 2]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y31]]; 
worker2[[3, 3]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y32]]; 
worker2[[3, 4]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y33]]; 
worker2[[3, 5]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y34]]; 
worker2[[3, 6]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y35]];
worker2[[4, 2]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y41]]; 
worker2[[4, 3]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y42]]; 
worker2[[4, 4]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y43]]; 
worker2[[4, 5]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y44]]; 
worker2[[4, 6]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y45]];
worker2[[5, 2]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y51]]; 
worker2[[5, 3]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y52]]; 
worker2[[5, 4]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y53]]; 
worker2[[5, 5]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y54]]; 
worker2[[5, 6]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y55]];
worker2[[6, 2]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y61]]; 
worker2[[6, 3]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y62]]; 
worker2[[6, 4]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y63]]; 
worker2[[6, 5]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y64]]; 
worker2[[6, 6]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y65]];
worker2[[7, 2]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y71]]; 
worker2[[7, 3]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y72]]; 
worker2[[7, 4]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y73]]; 
worker2[[7, 5]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y74]]; 
worker2[[7, 6]] = Checkbox[Dynamic[Y75]];

generalTable = workingTable;

TabView[{Worker1 -> Grid[worker1, Frame -> All], 
  Worker2 -> Grid[worker2, Frame -> All]}]

Dynamic@ArrayPlot[
  Boole[{{X21, X22, X23, X24, X25}, {X31, X32, X33, X34, X35}, {X41, 
 X42, X43, X44, X45}, {X51, X52, X53, X54, X55}, {X61, X62, X63, 
 X64, X65}, {X71, X72, X73, X74, X75}}], ImageSize -> Small]
```

[Comercial Software Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9QGAhZ-42LM)

Comment: I was going to point what is vague to me here but it seems everything is. Please ask specific questions that can be answered shortly and benefit future visitors. It is definitely to broad now :/

Comment: It is very simple. I need shift scheduler. A couple of people will work a couple of hours, but they have other jobs too, so I need to create a shift scheduler program to make best schedule. Do you see it is a very simple question: How can I make shift scheduler?

Comment: @forumcash Provide some sample input data and describe the qualities you are looking for in the output (the schedule). I think you can also do a better job at representing what you have tried so far, what is `availability` for example?

Comment: related [Creating a multi-tabbed ...](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15082/125)

Comment: Exactly what a shift scheduler is is not clear to me, but isn't it exactly what is asked for in the question linked by @kguler?